# function does't return a list as indented, but returns only one listelement instead

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, math

For the sake of practice, I am trying to calculate the following mathematical expression:

[image]

The x-value in the parameter is supposed to be a number - an int or float
The y-value in the parameter is supposed to be a list of numbers.

The function is supposed to return a list of values in the same length as the list y in the parameter.

For some embarrassing reason, I only manage to make the function return only one list element, that comes from the first of the two equations in the function.

The code in question is:

```
def f(x ,y):

    list = []

    for i in y:
        if y[i] <= 0:
            list.append(4 * (x ** 3) * y[i] - 2 * x * y[i])
        if y[i] > 0:
            list.append(4 * (x ** 3) * y[i] + 2 * x * y[i])

        return list

x_value = 2
y_values = [1,-2, 3, -7]

print(f(x_value, y_values))

#wanted output: [28, -56, 85, -252]

#actual output: [-56]
```

**My question is:**

- How do you make this function return a list with all the calculations? Like for example
  `[28, -56, 85, -252]` instead of the current output which is `[-56]`

This is probably an easy fix, but for some reason I am stuck.

Is there anybody kind enough to help me sort this out?

Comment: move the `return` to left on the same indent as `list = []`

Comment: And don't use `list` as name, it's built-in type.

Comment: @Brown Bear: That was my first thought, but for some reason, it gives me an error message saying the index is out of range.

Comment: @buran: thanks, I know, but this was just for translational purposes.

Comment: Strong emphasis on **don't use `list` as a variable name**. `list` is already the name of builtin type `list` in python. Reusing the name of the builtin to name something else is not only confusing, it can also have unintended side-effects. Imagine if I pass a law that "house" is now the name of my own house exclusively. Suddenly every legal contract that uses the word "house" is now referring to my house. I'm opening myself to a lot of trouble!! It wouldn't be that big an issue in other programming languages, but "python's names are dynamic, not scoped", meaning renaming affects everything.

Comment: @Stef: Hehe, yeah I know. Agreed! An embarrassing noob mistake by me:-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when you have `for i in y`, `i` is the actual value in `y`, not the index, so you don't use `y[i]`, you use `i` directly. Second, you should `return` the final list after the `for i in y` loop is over, so it needs to be outside the loop. And finally, don't use built-in names (such as `list`) as your own variable/function/class names, because it will overwrite the built-in names.

```
def f(x ,y):
    L = []

    for i in y:
        if i <= 0:
            L.append(4 * (x ** 3) * i - 2 * x * i)
        if i > 0:
            L.append(4 * (x ** 3) * i + 2 * x * i)

    return L
```

To use `i` as an index, you need to change the loop to `for i in range(len(y))`, and use `y[i]` as you did previously.

Also, if you use `numpy`, you can solve this as:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x_value = 2
>>> y_values = np.array([1,-2, 3, -7])

>>> 4 * x_value**3 * y_values + 2 * x_value * np.where(y_values <= 0, -y_values, y_values)
array([  36,  -56,  108, -196])
```

Comment: Also, as pointed out by people in the comments, I definitely prefer "L" as a variable name for the empty list rather than my noob choice "list" :-P.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it briefly with a list comprehension:

```
def f(x,y):
    return [4 * (x ** 3) * yy - 2 * x * yy if yy <= 0 
            else 4 * (x ** 3) * yy + 2 * x * yy for yy in y]
```

OR

```
def f(x, y)
    return [4 * (x ** 3) * yy + (int(yy > 0) - 0.5) * 4 * x * yy for yy in y]
```

To articulate the last example given that is could be a little bit cryptic: in both formulas, the two elements are always the same:

```
4 * (x ** 3) * yy

2 * x * yy
```

in the one case you sum them, in the other case you take the difference:

Hence we could write `f(x, y)` as:

```
def f(x, y):
    lst = []
    for yy in y:
        a, b = 4 * (x ** 3) * yy, 2 * x * yy
        lst.append(a + (1 if yy > 0 else -1) * b
    return lst
```

While there is a case to be esplicit with proper if close, there is also the case for not rewriting the same code/formulas.
Then can go even more compact knowing that `bool(yy > 0)` is 1 if `yy > 0` and 0 otherwise, so `2 * (bool(yy > 0) - 0.5)` is 1 and -1 respectively:

Comment: Thanks! Love the short form and use of list comprehension!